# Finding all circuits that contain a given edge

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms

Given a *directed graph* $G = (V, E)$ and an edge $e \in E$, I'm trying to come up with an algorithm to construct the minimum induced subgraph $H$ of $G$ with the property that every circuit in $G$ that traverses $e$ is in also in $H$.

As an example, suppose graph $G$ has vertices $V = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and edges $\{(1,2), (2,1), (2,3), (3,2), (3,1), (2,4), (4,3)\}$, and $e = (4, 3)$. The subgraph $H$ that the algorithm should output consists of the two circuits $2,4,3,2$ and $2,4,3,1,2$.

Of course, this problem can be solved by enumerating all circuits of $G$, but I'm hoping that someone here can come up with something better (that is, with strongly polynomial complexity, in the size of the graph) than that.

**EDIT:** I just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825249/find-all-vertices-on-all-simple-paths-between-two-vertices-in-an-undirected-gr) that solves the problem for *undirected* graphs, but it doesn't provide any directions for *directed* graphs. I don't see a straightforward generalisation to *directed* graphs from that post.

Comment: So what you are after is, after removing $e = uv$, every vertex that lie on a path from $u$ to $v$, am I right?  You can definitely do that in polytime using the polynomial time two-disjoint-paths algorithm, but there is probably a better way ...

Comment: In the subgraph computed with $e = uv$, every vertex lies on a path from $v$ to $u$. Thanks, I'll check out the two-disjoint-paths algorithm. I must confess I have never heard of it.

Comment: I just found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825249/find-all-vertices-on-all-simple-paths-between-two-vertices-in-an-undirected-gr) that solves the problem for _undirected_ graphs, but it doesn't provide any directions for _directed_ graphs. I don't see a straightforward generalisation to _directed_ graphs from that post.

Comment: Isn't $H$ the strongly connected component that includes $e$ (if any)?

Comment: No, consider a strongly connected graph $G$ with some edge $e$. Add a cycle in the following way: choose a random vertex $v$. Now add vertices $w_i$ to the graph and the cycle $C = v w_1 \ldots w_n v$. The resulting graph is still strongly connected, but cycle $C$ should not be in $H$.

Comment: @PålGD, I don't see how the two-disjoint-paths algorithm can do this (as a matter of fact I fear this problem is NP-Hard) Could you outline how it solves the problem by posting an answer to the original question?

Comment: @robertdg no, sorry, I didn't see that it was _directed_ graphs.  Two-disjoint paths is NP-complete on directed graphs, even two internally disjoint paths from $a$ to $b$ and from $b$ to $a$.  My idea was to, for $e = uv$, for every vertex $w$, if there are two disjoint paths from $u$ to $w$ and from $w$ to $v$, there is a cycle using $e$ containing $w$.  Repeat for every vertex.  However, it is unfortunately NP-complete on directed graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be NP-complete to compute, given an arc $e = uv$ of a directed graph $D = (V,A)$ whether there is a cycle containing some vertex $w$ using the arc $e$.  The instance to this problem is $(D,e,w)$.

By reducing from back-and-forth (two-disjoint paths from $a$ to $b$ and from $b$ to $a$), given an instance $(D',a,b)$ of back-and-forth, construct the instance $D$ where you make two copies of $a$, $a_1$ and $a_2$ and an arc going from $a_1$ to $a_2$.  The constructed instance is $(D,(a_1a_2),b)$.

Now, suppose there are two-disjoint paths from $a$ to $b$ and back, then there is a cycle from $a_2$ to $b$ and from $b$ to $a_1$, hence $b$ is on a cycle containing the arc $a_1a_2$.  For the reverse direction suppose that $b$ is on a cycle traversing the arc $a_1a_2$.  Then, in the original graph, there is a path from $a$ to $b$ and one from $b$ to $a$.  qed

Comment: Thanks, I was kind of afraid it would be NP-hard to construct the subgraph. It's interesting to see how such a seemingly simple problem is so difficult to solve in the presence of cycles.